# Convert CharSequence to BigDecimal

Tags: java

I did some search on this and all I found was that `BigDecimal` has a constructor that we can pass `String` to it and it will convert it for us.
But in my case what I have is a `java.lang.CharSequence` and what I need it to be is `BigDecimal`

What is the correct way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
new BigDecimal(myCharSeq.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`CharSequence.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29) together with the constructor you mentioned. `toString` documentation:

> Returns a string containing the characters in this sequence in the
>   same order as this sequence. The length of the string will be the
>   length of this sequence.

This turns into:

```
new BigDecimal(mySequence.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `toString()` on the `CharSequence` and build `BigDecimal` out of it. Javadoc is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .toString method of CharSequence Interface

I have corrected my self actually `CharSequence` is an interface which has its own toString() method.

toString(); -- Returns a string representation of the object.

Refer the ofiicial docs of CharSequnce Interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(charSeq.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(charSequence.length());
sb.append(charSequence);
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(sb.toString());
```

This protects you in case there's a problem with the charSequence concrete class implementation of toString().  CharSequence is an interface that could be backed by a user written concrete class.

Comment: The [docs for `CharSequence.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29) mandate that implementations must return the string equivalent, so why do all this extra work?

Comment: Just because the documentation says so, doesn't make it so.

Comment: What if there's a problem with the implementation of `length`? Or `StringBuilder`'s implementation of `toString`?

Comment: Seriously?  StringBuilder is a class and CharSequence is an interface.

Comment: Why do you use the simple `sb.append(charSequence)` statement? Your code would be much more enterprisy of you'd loop across all characters in the charSequence and add them one at a time to the StringBuilder. But wait, that wouldn't protect you either in case the StringBuilder constructor or the append method of the StringBuilder are buggy. And behave, what if there is a problem with the implementation of the BigDecimal class?